# How can I delete my MongoDB Atlas Project?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-cluster

When I click delete button it shows an:

**Error Message :**
"Project Name" has running Atlas clusters. All Atlas clusters need to be terminated before the project can be deleted. As Shown in picture below :

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You just need to **terminate the cluster before deleting the project**. Follow these steps:

1. Click three dots *(as seen on the picture)* and then click **"Terminate"**.
2. Click on the leaf on the top left side.
3. Then you can delete the project.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

1st Terminate your cluster[image]

Then visit your database by clicking "All Projects" And then deleting your project from there, I am sure that its gonna work that way

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found in the [official docs](https://docs.mongodb.com).
I think you have to terminate the currently running cluster.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]